# Trigger set insert row values to null

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

So I'm trying to write a trigger that when something is inserted into the database if it is over a specific time set the row values to null

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hi
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLASS_TIME ON class
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < '09:00' ) 
    OR (:NEW.CLASS_TIME > '18:00' )
    THEN    
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Due to low attendance no class cannot be scheduled at that time');
        SET NEW.STAFFNO = NULL; 
        SET NEW.CLASS_DAY = NULL; 
        SET NEW.CLASS_TYPE = NULL; 
        SET NEW.ROOMNUM = NULL;

    END IF; 
END;
```

All that I have found online shows that what Ive got is correct but I get the error on the STAFFNO. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: try :new.staffno := NULL; instead of set new.staffno....

Comment: `SET NEW.STAFFNO = NULL; ` is invalid in PL/SQL, please read the manual

Comment: just asking: when you raise an error, will the transaction be rolled back or will the trigger code go ahead with the updates to the record?

Comment: so by adding  UPDATE TUTPRAC SET STAFFNO = NULL;  to each one Ive got it to work. and @Adish it was rolled back

Comment: @Jason - even that update won't be executed if it's still after the raise_application_error; and if it's before the raise_application_error it will be rolled back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to decide:

- *either* you want the insert or update to fail when it's being done at undesired time
- *or* you want the insert or update to be processed, but with the columns set to null then.

You cannot have both.

In case you want to set the columns to NULL, this should be a **BEFORE** INSERT/UPDATE trigger, so the changed columns get written to the table. (In an AFTER INSERT/UPDATE trigger setting the fields to some value would not have any effect, becase they are not written.)

Then `SET NEW.STAFFNO = NULL;` is no valid PL/SQL, that would have to be `:NEW.STAFFNO := NULL;` instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hi
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF class_time ON class
  FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.class_time NOT BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:00')
BEGIN 
  :new.staffno := null; 
  :new.class_day := null; 
  :new.class_type := null; 
  :new.roomnum := null;
END;
```

Comment: That was so helpful thank you so much for taking the time to explain it properly to me