# MYSQL fires the trigger only when no value manually inserted - not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Hi I just need help as I am just new to mysql trigger.

I'm trying to create a trigger that if the project id is NULL then it will set it to new value but if someone has manually insert a value then it won't do anything.
I performed this but it ain't working on mysql.

`CREATE TRIGGER custom_autonums_pdl BEFORE INSERT ON project_details_logs
FOR each ROW
WHEN (new.projectid IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET new.projectid = getNextCustomSeqPl(year(now()),year(now())); 
END//
delimiter ;`

If someone can direct me to correct this, appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: ```CREATE TRIGGER custom_autonums_pdl BEFORE INSERT ON project_details_logs
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.projectid = COALESCE(NEW.projectid, some_expression_or_function(some_argument));```

Comment: @Akina do not post answers in comments, please

Comment: @larrie please define "ain't working"

Comment: @CaiusJard This is not an answer. I wait until OP says "it is not safe because ...". But if it turns out to solve the problem (which I personally strongly doubt), I'll move it to the answer.

Comment: @akina It's [not a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work); if you're thinking to put it as an answer, then you clearly think it could be an answer, so post it as an answer please. This half-effort if "I think this might be an answer but I don't want to test it and I don't want to get any downvotes so I'll put it as a comment and maybe make it an answer later" is not what SO is about. We research and make good answers

Comment: @larrie I could have surmised as much; tell us something that will help us to help you **like the exact error message**

Comment: @Caius Jard It is giving me an error when I'm trying to run the query. Error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN (new.projectid IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET new.projectid = getNextCustomSeqPl' at line 3

Comment: @Akina When the user has manually input a project ID thru insert, then the trigger must not do anything but if they leave it blank, then it will generate the value.

Comment: @larrie what tutorial/advice site are you following that indicates mariadb allows a WHEN clause in a trigger spec?

Comment: @Caius Jard I'm not sure why it was set to mariadb. Is there a way I could change that to mysql as default since I just installed the xampp without advance configuration? Anyway, I have checked this thread to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410994/trigger-set-insert-row-values-to-null

Comment: I wouldn't immediately jump to MariaDB being a bad thing; it has a lot of features not available in eg MySQL 5.7 though mysql 8 was a major overhaul that really brought things up to date. Asking how to switch from Maria to MySQL as part of your xampp install would be more a question for SuperUser because it doesn't involve coding, just software config

Comment: *When the user has manually input a project ID thru insert* ??? User manually writes this insert query text??? Or maybe you mean that the user fills (or remains blank) some textbox in some visual interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a MariaDb/MySQL trigger that uses the WHEN syntax available in other major RDBMS - you'd need to run the trigger for every insert and conditionally act on the id:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER custom_autonums_pdl 
BEFORE INSERT ON project_details_logs 
FOR each ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF new.projectid IS NULL THEN
      SET new.projectid = getNextCustomSeqPl(year(now()),year(now()));
    END IF;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Wow, never thought it was just that! Thanks a lot for fixing my problem and I learned something new. :)